# Assessing a distribution from multiple samples of its mean

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I face a random variable whose distribution I don't know.

Someone draws a sample of k observations from a population and tells me their average. He repeats the process m times.

I assume m is in order of magnitude of hundreds.

If 1 < k < 20, What can I tell about the population variance?

What about other lower moments?

If k=1, I can trivially draw the emplirical distribution. What is the closest analoug for 1 < k < 20?

Comment: You shouldn't talk about the mean of a sample, the mean is the true unknown parameter, what you do from a sample is average them to get an estimate of the mean.  I assume that's what you mean anyway.  In which case the central limit theorem says this approaches normal as $k$ gets large, so I don't see how you can recover the original distribution from just this information.

Comment: Thank you @Gregory Grant.
Sould k be small and m large, intuitively I guess I'd have a distribution similar to the original with smaller variance.
Should k be very large, you are right. 
There must be something I know for other values of k. I wish to formalize it.

Comment: If $k$ is small and $m$ large then you can say more.  Obviously if $k=1$ and $m$ large then you have an empirical estimate of the distribution.  But once you average two observations of your distribution it already looks quite different from the original and starts to look normal pretty quickly.  What makes you believe it is possible to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: There is a [simple relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Basic_manipulations_of_distributions) between the characteristic function of the original distribution and that of the distribution of the sample mean. How well one can reconstruct the characteristic function from $m$ samples, though, I don't know. You may get better answers by migrating your question to http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, what makes me believe I can partially reconstruct the original distribution with small k, is a large enough m.

Comment: You're not using the word "sample" correctly.  You're talking about $m$ samples, and each sample has size $k$. $\qquad$

Comment: @GregoryGrant : It is perfectly standard to use the term "sample mean" or "mean of the sample". $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to say ``someone draws a sample of $k$ *observations* from a population,'' and so on. Unfortunately, some textbooks and software packages
use 'sample' where the proper terminology is 'observation'. (Although I like Minitab for many purposes, its 'dialog boxes' consistently misuse the
word *sample*.)

Note that $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{k}$ 
and $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/k,$ where $\sigma^2$ is the population variance.

Now suppose you treat the $m$ sample means $\bar X$ (each based on $k$
individual observations) as data, and find their sample variance, calling
it $S_{\bar X}^2.$ Then $S_{\bar X}^2$ estimates $\sigma^2/k,$ so that
$kS_{\bar X}^2$ is an estimate of $\sigma^2.$

Now you have the mean of the $m$ sample means, as an estimate of the population
mean $\mu$ and $kS_{\bar X}^2$ as an estimate of the population variance $\sigma^2.$ With similar approaches, you might be able to get (decreasingly
efficient) estimates of the population skewness and kurtosis. (I say 'decreasingly  efficient' because, as in the 2nd Comment of @Gregory Grant,
you lose information about the shape of population distribution when you take means of individual observations. The CLT is your ``enemy'' here.)

Estimating $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ is not
the same thing as knowing the shape of the population, but it may be a
start toward describing the population.

**However,** if you were able to see all $km$ of the individual observations,
you could make a histogram of them and get some idea of the shape of the
population density function. Better yet, you could make an empirical CDF 
curve (ECDF) of the $n = km$ observations. (That is better than a histogram,
because information is lost in sorting data into histogram bins.) Sort the data, an ECDF is a step function, starting at $0$ before the first observation, jumping
up by $1/n$ at each observation,  and reaching $1$ by the last observation. 
For moderately large $n$, the ECDF should be a reasonable approximation of the population CDF.

**Numerical example.** With $m = 1000$ and $k = 100,$ we take $n = mk$ observations from
the population distribution $Gamma(shape=3, rate=1/5),$ which has
mean $\mu = 15$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 75.$ Below we see that
the grand mean of all $n$ observations is 15.05 and that their variance
is 74.8, both good estimates of their corresponding population
parameters. (Simulation and computations in R statistical software.)

```
 m = 1000;  k = 100;  x = rgamma(m*k, 3, 1/5)
 mean(x);  var(x)
 ## 15.0481
 ## 74.79534
```

Now split these observations into $m = 1000$ samples, each with $k = 100$
observations. Each of the 1000 rows in the matrix `DTA` is a sample.
We find the means `a` of each sample. These are the $\bar X$s above.
Then `mean(a)` is the grand mean mentioned above, which is a good
estimate of $\mu$. And `k*var(a)` is $kS_{\bar X}^2$ above.Again
these are good estimates of $\mu$ and (alsmost as) good of $\sigma^2.$
(A little information was lost for estimating $\sigma^2$ when we
use sample means to estimate.)

```
DTA = matrix(x, nrow = m)
 a = rowMeans(DTA)
 mean(a);  k*var(a)
 ## 15.0481
 ## 76.28247
```

There are three graphs below. (1) a histogram of the 1000 $\bar X$s,
which starts to look a lot like normal because of the averaging (averaging obscures the true ehape of the population distribution); 
(2) a histogram of all $n = km$ individual observations, along with
the density curve of $Gamma(3, 1/5);$ and (3) an ECDF plot of the
$n$ observations (in black), with the CDF curve of $Gamma(3, 1/5)$
running almost exactly through it (in green). [Maybe right-click on
the figure and select 'new window' for aa bigger version and better detail.]

[image]